# Unwrapping snapshot data from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on a starter iOS project. I have been looking around and can see the issues but the solutions have not worked yet for me, or I am simply struggling with the concepts of unwrapping the snapshot data and the optional types used in Swift.

My code currently looks as follows, for a simple "tasks" collection in Firebase and a Task class defined in my code.

```
db.collection("tasks").addSnapshotListener { QuerySnapshot, error in
        if let querySnapShot = QuerySnapshot{
            self.tasks =  QuerySnapshot.documents.compactMap{ document in
                document.data(as: Task.self)
            }
        }
    }
```

The error retrieved now is

```
Value of optional type 'QuerySnapshot?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'documents' of wrapped base type 'QuerySnapshot'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `querySnapShot.documents` instead of `QuerySnapshot.documents`

```
if let querySnapShot = QuerySnapshot{
  self.tasks =  querySnapShot.documents.compactMap{ document in
      document.data(as: Task.self)
  }
}
```

BTW it's always better to make it start with small letter

```
querySnapshot, error in
```

To be

```
db.collection("tasks").addSnapshotListener { querySnapShot, error in
   if let querySnapShot = querySnapShot {
      self.tasks =  querySnapShot.documents.compactMap{ document in
                document.data(as: Task.self)
       }
   }
}
```